# White flash while navigation bar moves in and out of view

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

First of all here's a **link** to the website so you know what I am talking about:
https://lefkosp.netlify.app/
**Disclaimer:** please visit the website from a **PC** because it is not yet responsive.
I also have the source code on github:
https://github.com/lefkosp/my-portfolio

I want the nav bar to move out of view the moment you scroll down, then come back into view if you scroll back up and just move out again if you continue scrolling down.

I also want to add a box-shadow property and a backdrop-filter blur when the nav bar is into view but not at the beginning of the website. I managed to make this but I have a problem with a **weird white flash** that occurs **right before** the navbar starts moving, either **into view** or **out of the view.**

This is how I **calculate** which class to **add** and which to **remove** based on scroll

```
  useEffect(() => {
    document.addEventListener("scroll", function (e) {
      if (window.oldScroll > window.scrollY) {
        document.querySelector(".nav").classList.remove("move-nav");
        document.querySelector(".nav").classList.add("secondary-nav");
      }
      if (!(window.oldScroll > window.scrollY)) {
        document.querySelector(".nav").classList.add("move-nav");
        document.querySelector(".nav").classList.remove("secondary-nav");
      }
      if (!window.scrollY) {
        document.querySelector(".nav").classList.remove("move-nav");
        document.querySelector(".nav").classList.remove("secondary-nav");
      }
      window.oldScroll = window.scrollY;
    });
  }, []);
```

and these are the **classes** I use

```
.nav {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 1rem 3rem;
  z-index: 100;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
}

.move-nav {
  box-shadow: 0 15px 30px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.938);
  transform: translateY(-72px);
  backdrop-filter: blur(20px);
}

.secondary-nav {
  box-shadow: 0 15px 30px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.397);
  backdrop-filter: blur(20px);
}
```

Appreciate any help I can get. Even tips for the website other than this problem since I am kind of a newbie. Thank you!

Comment: Could you describe the actual problem you're seeking help with more clearly? You describe a white flash - when and where does this occur? I'm not seeing it.

Comment: yes, sorry for not being clear enough. The white flash occurs at the top of the navbar. If you scroll down a bit and then back up for the navbar to get back into view you can see it flashing white and then switching into the correct color. Please let me know if I can provide you with more info. Thank you @Andru

Comment: `scroll` listeners need to be `passive`, btw: https://web.dev/uses-passive-event-listeners - and you should never read from DOM layout properties after doing anything that can mutate the previously-rendered layout (in this case, you should `return` immediately after setting `classList` or use `} else if {` so you can't check `window.scrollY` twice)

Comment: Thank you for the comment @Dai I tried both making the listener passive and returning immediately after setting classList and using else if. Unfortunately didn't seem to fix the issue.

Comment: @Lefy I cannot reproduce the white-flash you describe on my computer (Chrome 99 on Windows 10 20H2, AMD Radeon GPU)

Comment: @Dai oh that's weird, I uploaded a video to youtube that shows the problem that I am having https://youtu.be/zjh6pSoi3DQ also I noticed that it doesn't occur in fullscreen mode which is also weird.

Answer (score 0):

I think the white flash you're referring to is the browser's springback scroll.

The simplest solution is to set the `background-color` on your html element to the same colour as your background.

```css
html {
  background-color: #000;
}
```

This leaves the spring-scroll in effect, but will make the spring area black.

You can also disable spring scrolling altogether with `overscroll-behavior-y: none;`. Last I checked, this doesn't work for iOS Safari, which needs a hackier solution.

```css
html, body{
  overscroll-behavior-y: none;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer Andru, unfortunately I tried both, but nothing worked. I use Brave btw, I checked on Edge as well for the overscroll-behavior-y but didn't work either.